# JAVA runtime error on UVa online judge 100

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve this problem by JAVA.
But it appears runtime error when I load input as string and parse to Int...
(the code was commented out)

Then I use nextInt() method to load input, and it doesn't show runtime error anymore.

After modified the output to

```
System.out.println(arr3[0]+" "+arr3[1]+" "+now);
```

Result was Accepted.

So...what's wrong with my previous code ? 
It seems OK on my computer but always runtime error in UVA online judge .
Thanks all~

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        int now = 0;
    //  String str = sc.nextLine();
    //  String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    //  arr2[1] = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
    //  arr2[0] = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int[] arr2 = new int[2];
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        arr[0] = arr2[0] = sc.nextInt();
        arr[1] = arr2[1] = sc.nextInt();    


        int tmp;
        if(arr2[0]>arr2[1]){
            tmp = arr2[0];
            arr2[0] =arr2[1];
            arr2[1] = tmp;  
        }

        for (int i = arr2[0]; i < arr2[1]+1; i++) {
            long a = i;
            int count = 0;

            while (a != 1) {

                count++;
                if ((a % 2) != 0) 
                    a = 3 * a + 1;
                else 
                    a = a / 2;
            }
            count++;

            if (count > now) 
            now = count;
        }

        System.out.println(" "+now);
    }
}
```

Comment: UVA Online Judge compilers are really weird. I tried a few problems there using different languages (C, C++, Java) but none was accepted.

I moved to CodeForces.com and it is way better than UVA imo. You should check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scanner.next…` skips different kind of white-space while `str.split(" ")` only skips a single space. Further `Scanner.nextInt` does different transformations, e.g. to accept localized numbers, while `Integer.parseInt` accepts only one format. It depends on the input data whether it makes a difference.

Comment: so what format of input will cause the situation?
The input of UVa100 just like 
1 100
100 10000

Comment: In this case the problem is that you called `nextLine`. That gives you the *entire line* and then `split(" ")` will give you an array of length `4`. But you used only the first two numbers and ignored the next two.